# Does the Keras implementation in TF2 support everything native Keras can do with TF1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

We are working with Keras on top of TensorFlow 1.x. But now that TF 2.0 is coming we are thinking of switching to that update, using the Keras API implementation built into TF 2.0.

But before we do so, I would like to ask you guys: Do you know whether the Keras implementation in TF 2.0 does support everything native Keras does with TF 1.0, or are there any features missing?

Moreover, will I be able to use my Keras code 1:1 with the new TF 2.0 implementation of the Keras API, or do we need to re-write parts of our existing Keras code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use TensorFlow, then I highly recommend you to switch and use the TensorFlow implementation of Keras (i.e. `tf.keras`) because it will support more features of TF and also would be much more efficient and optimized than native Keras.

Actually, Keras maintainers released a new version (2.2.5) of Keras a few days ago (after more than 10 months with no new release!) and they also recommend to use `tf.keras`. Here are the [release notes](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.2.5):

> Keras 2.2.5 is the last release of Keras that implements the 2.2.* API. It is the last release to only support TensorFlow 1 (as well as Theano and CNTK).
>
> The next release will be 2.3.0, which makes significant API changes and add support for TensorFlow 2.0. The 2.3.0 release will be the last major release of multi-backend Keras. Multi-backend Keras is superseded by `tf.keras`.
>
> At this time, we recommend that Keras users who use multi-backend Keras with the TensorFlow backend switch to `tf.keras` in TensorFlow 2.0. `tf.keras` is better maintained and has better integration with TensorFlow features.

This: "Multi-backend Keras is superseded by `tf.keras`" is a strong indicator that it is better to switch to `tf.keras`, especially if you are still at the beginning of your project.